# Is there any way to debug IBM Rhapsody plugins inside Rhapsody?

Tags: java, rhapsody

I wrote a Java plugin for IBM Rhapsody, the plugin works as expected in Eclipse, but once I start Rhapsody, it won't open. I put some logs into the code to check where the program stops, but it won't show either. Interestingly, all the logs show in Rhapsody, if a start the program from eclipse. But not if i start from Rhapsody. A previous version worked in Rhapsody too but for some reason this version won't. Is there anything I can do inside Rhapsody to debug the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem since then. By making a runnable jar file, I got an error : "Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment ". I changed the compiler compliance version to 1.8 then it worked.

Comment: See my detailed comment on troubleshooting plugins at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476211/ibm-rhapsody-log-is-empty-when-i-print-from-plugin-using-java-api/51484981#51484981